# Когда я пытаюсь достать сформированный массив из js файла, и поместить его в html, при отображении появляется набор символов, хотя metaCharset есть

Tags: javascript, html, массивы, arraylist

Всем привет.
Js файл должен находиться отдельно потому что к нему должны обращаться несколько файлов параллельно , из за этого нет возможности его впилить в HTML.

Js файл, который мы имеем ввиду, состоит из нескольких массивов, в последствии формируя, выборочным путем, еще один массив, который мы и вызываем для отображения на странице HTML.
Но когда я его вызываю, получается так, что массив представляется в виде инопланетных знаков, как будто страница HTML, не видит Meta Charset.

Может кто-нибудь встречался?

Всем благ.

```js
const listExe1 = [{
    name: 2
  },
  {
    name: 1
  },
];

const listExe2 = [{
    name: 3
  },
  {
    name: 4
  },
  {
    name: 5
  },
  {
    name: 5
  },
]

const newExe = [];

listExe1.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
var b = listExe1[0]
newExe.push(b)

listExe2.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
var b = listExe2[0]
newExe.push(b)

listExe2.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
var b = listExe2[0]
newExe.push(b)
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="scriptJS.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="tren">
    <script>
      document.write(`${newExe[0].name}<br />`)
      document.write(`${newExe[1].name}<br />`)
    </script>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Про верьте кодировку ваших файлов html и js...

Comment: Приведенные примеры массивов - не массивы.